# Can we check that if the selected image is in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

How can we check that if selected image is in Landscape or in portrait mode...

Actually i am using imagePicker and want to make it look perfect.....
because if it is in portrait mode then there is some white space in my imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before selecting the image ,you could use the [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class to get the current `orientation` of Device,
Use below to get the screen orientation.

```
UIDeviceOrientation myDeviceCurrentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Apple documentation for [UIDeviceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).